# What does file.path in gulp-exec mean

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have some questions about: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec#usage

```
gulp.src('./**/**')
    .pipe(exec('git checkout <%= file.path %> <%= options.customTemplatingThing %>', options))
    .pipe(exec.reporter(reportOptions));
```

What do `<%= =>` and `file.path` mean?
Do they come from node ? Could you give another example ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= =>`

These are [`lodash.template`](https://lodash.com/docs#template) "interpolate" delimiters. They allow you to insert arbitrary values into strings. You can provide those values in the second argument to `exec()`. Those values are then available as properties of the `options` object in the string. Everything from `<%=` to `=>` is replaced with the value of the `options` property in between.

**Example:**

```
gulp.src('.')
  .pipe(exec('cp <%= options.in %> <%= options.out %>', {in:'foo', out:'bar'}));
```

In the above:

- `<%= options.in %>` is replaced with `foo`
- `<%= options.out %>` is replaced with `bar`

So the command that gets executed is `cp foo bar`.

---

`file.path`

The `options` object is not the only object that is available for interpolation. The command in `exec()` is executed for each [Vinyl file](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl) emitted from `gulp.src()`. Each time the command is executed the `file` object refers to the particular vinyl file that the command is executed on.

**Example:**

```
gulp.src(['foo.txt', 'bar.txt'])
  .pipe(exec('rm <%= file.path %>', {}));
```

This executes two commands, one for each file matched by `gulp.src()`:

- `rm /path/to/foo.txt`
- `rm /path/to/bar.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but how do I make lodash work in a gulpfile.ts?

Answer (score 1):

It's showing the path for the files passing through the stream for the Gulp task, which is from [Vinyl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl).  [Vinyl](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl) will have more information for what else you could use.

For example, you could get the filename by doing this instead

```
<%= file.relative %>
```